# Beginner programer confusion on while statement using fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

Below is a program I am trying to understand.  The only part that I am confused about is the while statement being `while fscanf(....) == 4` as well as the part `if(...) == 0`.

Could someone explain this line and its purpose to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct str_student {
    char UFID[9];
    char firstname[20];
    char major[10];
    int age;
};


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     FILE *fStud = fopen("students.dat", "r");
     struct str_student S[11];

    int i, n = 0;
    while( fscanf(fStud, "%s %s %s %i", S[n].UFID, S[n].firstname, S[n].major, &S[n].age) == 4)          
    {    if(( S[n].age > 40 ) && ( strcmp(S[n].major, "ECE") == 0 ))
            n = n + 1;
    }

    printf("\nStudents of the ECE Department who are 41 or more years old:\n");
    for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
         printf("%s\n", S[i].UFID);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `fscanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), to see what it returns. Also search for the other function (`strcmp`) on that site for more information about that.

Answer (score 5):

`fscanf` returns the number of fields that were read. The format string `"%s %s %s %i"` has four fields, so `while (fscan(...) == 4)` loops as long as `fscanf` is able to read all four fields. It'll exit if it hits end-of-file (EOF), or if the file contains improperly formatted data (e.g. the `%i` field is not a valid integer).

`strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings match. `if (strcmp(a, b) == 0)` is the most common way of checking whether two strings are equal in C.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining

```
if(( S[n].age > 40 ) && ( strcmp(S[n].major, "ECE") == 0 ))
    n = n + 1;
```

Both parts of the expression

```
if (condition1 && condition2)
```

must be true.

The first part is fairly obviously true if `age > 40`.

The second part is true if the two strings compared are the same, when `strcmp(...) == 0`.

The results of `fscanf()` have already been stored in array index `[n]`, but the index is incremented only if the conditions are true. Otherwise the results will be overwritten by the next data line (or discarded if there isn't another data line).